# Factoring large polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I'm asked questions like to find the zeros, and multplicities of the $\mathbb{C}$-polynomials

$$f(z) =z^6 +4z^2 - 1 \hspace{10mm} , |z| < 1$$
or worse yet
$$f(z)=z^{87}+36z^{57}+71z^4+z^3-z+1 \hspace{10mm}, 1<|z|<2$$

Surely factoring these things isn't the right approach...and I can't seem to think of a way to find them otherwise? We've been looking at some nice things we can do *if we know* what the zeros/singularities are, but as for finding them.. I don't know.

Thanks for any push in the right direction!

Comment: A Cauchy integral can tell you the number of zeroes in e.g. the disc  $|z|<1$, also their sum, the sum of their squares etc. Since I expect there to be way less than 87 roots in the domain in question, this should give you a linear or maybe quadratic.

Comment: Man how does everyone here know so much. You didn't even blink solving that.

Comment: $4|z|^2>|z^6-1|$ for $|z|=1$, so Rouche Theorem tells you how many they are. Also, for the second one, $71|z|^4 > |z^{87}+..|$ on $|z| = 1$ and $|z|^{87} >...$ on $|z| =2$.

Comment: You can find multiple factors of $p$ by computing the greatest common divisor of $p$ and $p'$ ... if there are any.

Comment: @Chloe.H You're absolutely right: you shouldn't, and most likely can't, factorise them. The Abel–Ruffini theorem tells us that there is no general algebraic solution to polynomial equations of degree five or higher.